# Код яндекс метрики блокирует Lightbox на iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, lightbox

Проблема в следующем: при размещении кода яндекс.метрики на сайте, перестает работать lightbox на iPad, iPhone.
Браузеры - Safari, Chrome. Пробовал разные лайтбоксы.
На декстопе - все работает без нареканий. Без кода метрики - тоже, проблем нет.
В чем может быть причина? Как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: в консоли пусто?

Comment: да, пусто.

Comment: ммм, а если местами скрипты поменять, тоже пусто?

Comment: В общем, проблема либо с метрикой, либо с конструкцией вида

<a href='Path1'>
   <i></i>
   <img src='Path2'>
</a>
Убирая либо метрику, либо тэг <i>, получаем работающий lightbox

P.S. Код не мой, зачем там этот тэг, не знаю, возможно требовались подписи